# How do I make a form action pass input text to a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, user-input

Ok so here's my problem. I am making a WikiViewer using Wikipedia's API. I have a search box (input type text) where I would like to be able to type in a query and just hit 'enter' to have it return my results, rather than having an actual submit button. It needs to be an actual form bc otherwise mobile devices won't be able to just hit return/go/etc instead of having to press a button. I tried it with a 'enter' key press event, but I can't find anything like this for mobile devices and I'm pretty sure they don't even exist.

Here is my working code, without the form element.

```html
<div class='container'>
 <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..." id='search'>
 <input type='submit' value=''>
 <div id='article'>
 </div>
</div>
```

```js
const ready = () => {

 const getWiki = (text) => {
  $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=text&section=0&page=" + `${text}` + "&callback=?",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   async: false,
   dataType: "json",
   success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) => {
    const markup = data.parse.text["*"];
    const text = $('<div></div>').html(markup);
    text.find('a').each(function() {
     $(this).replaceWith($(this).html())
    });
    text.find('sup').remove();
    text.find('.mw-ext-cite-error').remove();
    $('#article').html($(text).find('p'));
   },
   error: error => {}
  });
 };

 $('#search').on('keypress', (e) => {
  if (e.which === 13)
   getWiki($('#search').val())
 });
 
};

$(document).ready(ready);
```

If anyone knows of an easier way to accomplish this without needing the form for mobile devices, I'm all ears. As always, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can surround your inputs with a `<form>` element and use the event `submit` to get the submit of the form. (Remember to do `e.preventDefault()`, so it won't refresh the page)

Comment: Did you read my question or did I just not explain it very well haha I realize I can make it a form, but then I need a way of passing the text from my text input into my getWiki function to get a response from Wikipedia. I want users to be able to do this by just hitting enter, whether they're on a mobile device or not. WITHOUT having a submit button.

I've fiddled with it for hours making it a form, and not a form, trying to accomplish this effect on both mobile and desktop browsers. I would edit it to include the version that didn't work, using a form, if I could figure out how to edit it.

Comment: I've created a snippet to show what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a submit button. What I said was to create a form in order to user its default behavior to get a submit from the form:

```js
var $searchForm = $('#search_form');

$searchForm.on('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var searchField = e.target.search.value;
  alert(searchField);
  //use your searchField to pass to the function
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
    <form id="search_form">
 <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search..." id='search'>
    </form>
 <div id='article'>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh wow I'm sorry, I totally misunderstood you. I thought you just didn't see that I had tried using a form before. What you wrote works like a gem on a normal browser, but still no dice when it comes to iOS :(. Any idea why? The 'return' button doesn't seem to be doing anything. And as I understand it, hitting return/done or whatever should submit forms on mobile devices, correct?

Comment: I've changed the type of the field to `search`. I can't test it right now if it makes the "return" key works like a submit action.

Comment: Wow, it worked perfectly. No idea why that made such a huge difference but it did haha. You've made my first experience actually posting a problem on this site wayyy better than I thought it would be. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: Probably a stupid question but... how do I mark your post as the answer? O.o

Comment: You're welcome! That's why semantics is for. In this case, it's always better to use a `form` when dealing with inputs. About the type `search` of the input, the mobile browser knows how to deal with it the way we expect.

Comment: [To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. Guess I just don't know enough about how stuff acts in different environments. Thanks again!

Comment: I tried but it said something about votes cast by people with less than 15 reputation are recorded but not displayed publicly and since I just made this account I guess I fall into that category haha.

Comment: Okay, I see. Hahaha